# Ubuntu 22.04 hangs on shutdown

Tags: shutdown

I made a new installation on Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 5.15.0-46) and it hangs on shutdown.
Last message: "kvm: exiting hardware virtualization"
I tried shutdown -H -P +0 which did not work.
Updating to Kernel 5.19.2 did also not help.

When I run from installation  USB stick, it boots only in safe grafic mode, and when I click "try Ubuntu", shutdown works fine.

Does anyone have an good advise (hopefully not to complicated, because I have not so much experience).Can the NVIDIA card be the issue?

```
System:
  Host: si-Aspire-E5-771G Kernel: 5.19.2-051902-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: GNOME 42.2 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i7-4510U bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
    L2: 512 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 797 min/max: 800/3100 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 795
    4: 796
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 840M] driver: nouveau v: kernel
  Device-3: Sunplus Innovation Laptop Integrated WebCam HD type: USB
    driver: uvcvideo
  Display: wayland server: X.Org v: 1.22.1.1 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1
    compositor: gnome-shell driver: gpu: i915 resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
Startup finished in 3.182s (kernel) + 36.868s (userspace) = 40.050s 
graphical.target reached after 36.858s in userspace
30.953s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.346s gpu-manager.service
 6.503s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 3.971s systemd-journal-flush.service
 2.390s dev-sda3.device
 1.540s dev-loop6.device
 1.536s networkd-dispatcher.service
 1.449s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ABF6\x2d51D9.service
 1.139s snapd.service
 1.077s dev-loop9.device
```

Comment: Try disabling `Intel VT` in the BIOS. Sometimes it reads `Intel Virtualization Technology` or `Intel VT-x`

Comment: There is no item in the BIOS about virtualization (VT)

Comment: I tried to get rid of kvm intel:
```
lsmod | grep kvm
kvm_intel             430080  0
kvm                  1105920  1 kvm_intel
```

`sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove qemu-kvm`
»qemu-system-x86« instead of »qemu-kvm« choosen
0 updated, 0 new installed, 0 removed and 8 not update
but actually nothing changed

Then I tried:
```
modprobe -r kvm_intel
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:799 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'kvm_intel': Operation not permitted
```
I can not get rid of kvm intel and use qemu-system-x86